# How to load XML data from HTTP request in ember 2.1

Tags: ember.js

I am new in Ember.js and I am having trouble connecting my app to the backend data.

I am currently using ember data v.2.1, ember v.2.1, ember inspector v.1.9.3

We are upgrading an existing app and we want to use ember as front-end framework. The app right now is java based and is using xsl on the front.

What I need to do is to connect through HTML request with ember to the existing backend which return XML and convert it to json so I can use it in ember. I tried to follow this example : https://bendyworks.com/old-new-soap-ember-js/ without any luck.

With the inspector I can see my model, but I can't load any data in it.

I have a model that look like this:

```
// app/models/get-menu.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

    export default DS.Model.extend({
      description: DS.attr('string'),
      url: DS.attr('string')
    });
```

I have an adapter:

```
//adapters/menu.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'
      },

    findAll: function() {
        return this.ajax('LinkForHTTPRequest','POST');
      },
      ajaxOptions: function(url) {
          // pretend to be a 'GET' to avoid certain nastiness in default impl
          var hash = DS.RESTAdapter.prototype.ajaxOptions.call(this, url);
          hash.type = 'GET';
          hash.dataType = 'xml';
          return hash;
        }
});
```

and I have a serializer :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  extractArray: function(store, xmlDoc) {
    var $ = Ember.$;
    var xml = $(xmlDoc).find('TMSMENUS').text();
    var innerXml = $($.parseXML(xml)).find('MENUS');

    return innerXml.map(function(idx, el) {
      return {
        id: idx,
        name: $(el).find('description').text(),
        url: $(el).find('url').text(),
      };
    }).get();
  }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like you need to implement a custom serializer to convert the output into a format that Ember Data understands.

Comment: I've updated my post for more details

Comment: I'm not sure `extractArray` is a method of `JSONSerializer`.

Comment: You should be using one of the `normalize` functions http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_new-jsonserializer-and-restserializer-api